# How to insert image in website (Asp.net mvc 5)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to make a user choose a picture from their pc and upload it to my website, however it didn't open the browse option to choose a picture and return to the list view.

Here's my code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddRestuarantItem(RestaurantItem restaurantItem, HttpPostedFileBase certificateImage)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (certificateImage != null)
                    {
                        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"),
                            Path.GetFileName(certificateImage.FileName));

                        certificateImage.SaveAs(path);
                    }

                    ViewBag.FileStatus = "Image uploaded successfully";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ViewBag.FileStatus = "Error while image uploading.";
                }
            }

            restaurantItems.Insert(restaurantItem);
            restaurantItems.Commit();

            return RedirectToAction("RestaurantItemList");
        }
```

and Here's my View:

```html
@model WorldOfHalal.Models.RestaurantItem

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddRestuarantItem";
}

<h2>AddRestuarantItem</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRestuarantItem", "Restaurant", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>RestaurantItem</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CertificateImageUrl, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CertificateImageUrl, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "CertificateImageUrl" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CertificateImageUrl, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="image" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-success">
                @ViewBag.FileStatus
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put an input with type="file" to upload the picture, like this :

```
 <input type="file" name="certificateImage"/>
```

Comment: It didn't insert image in database :S

Comment: We store the image inside the folder on the server. You only need to store the image name in the database.